# Preparing a state $|\chi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, density-operator, quantum-statistics, quantum-states

Consider the spin state of a particle of spin $s=\frac{1}{2}$. As far as the spin degrees of freedom are concerned, the operators $\textbf{S}^2$ and $S_z$ form the complete set of commuting observables, i.e., $[\textbf{S}^2,S_z]=0$. Suppose we measure both $\textbf{S}^2$ and $S_z$. Measurement of $S_z$ will either yield the values $m_s=+\frac{1}{2}$ or $m_s=-\frac{1}{2}$. Also, assume that 50% of the time we find the particle to be in the $+\frac{1}{2}$ state (denoted by $|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle$) and the other 50% of the time in the $m_s=-\frac{1}{2}$ state (denoted by $|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$).

1. Based on this information, what does the above ensemble represent? Is it a pure or a mixed ensemble? My guess is that it is a mixed ensemble.
2. If pure (which I doubt), the normalized spin state $|\chi\rangle$ of the particle can be written as $$|\chi\rangle=\frac{e^{i\phi_1}}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\frac{e^{i\phi_2}}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\tag{1}$$ where $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are arbitrary phases. Hence, the spin state of the system is not uniquely specified because the relative phase can not be fixed.
3. How does one prepare a state with $\phi_1=\phi_2=0$ so that $$|\chi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle\tag{2}?$$

Comment: Might be a good idea to include in your title that this question is specifically about the phase factor

Comment: 1. *"Hence, the state of the system cannot be uniquely specified even though it is a pure state."* - why is this surprising? You've given incomplete information - one real parameter, namely the probability to be in a given $S_z$ state - but the state of space , the Bloch sphere, has two real parameters. Please don't ask questions to which the answer likely is simply "Yes." 2. If this is meant to be a question about experimental procedure this seems to be a very different question from the first and should be asked separately. I'd advise to remove/clarify the first and expand on the second.

Comment: @ACuriousMind 1. How does one a priori know whether the answer will be yes? A question is usually asked when there is a confusion on the part of the person who asks. 2. I don't think it's an experimental question. It's a conceptual question.

Comment: If it is not an experimental question (which would not be off-topic!), then I don't know what you mean by "prepare".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you've laid out,

> [If we measure $S_z$, then] 50% of the time we find the particle to be in the $+\frac{1}{2}$ state (denoted by $|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle$) and the other 50% of the time in the $m_s=-\frac{1}{2}$ state (denoted by $|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$)

there is not enough information to tell whether the system is in a pure or a mixed state. As two concrete examples, both

- the completely mixed state $\rho=\frac12\big(|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle\langle\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}|+|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle\langle\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}|\big)$, and
- the pure state $|\psi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\big(|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle+|\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle\big)$,

are compatible with those measurement statistics. The most general state that will produce those measurement outcomes has a density matrix of the form
$$
\rho = \begin{pmatrix}\frac12 & \rho_{12}^* \\ \rho_{12} & \frac12\end{pmatrix},
$$
in the $\{|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\rangle,|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle\}$ basis, where $\rho_{12}$ is the coherence between the two basis states; this can be zero (giving the completely mixed state) or any complex number with a modulus up to $1/2$ (in which case the state is a pure state, with the phase of $\rho_{12}$ indicating the relative phase between the basis states in the superposition), or somewhere in between (indicating partial coherence between the two states).

---

If you explicitly know that you *don't* have any more information about the state, then you default to the completely mixed state. This is because, as you note, to be able to talk about a pure state with those statistics, it needs to be an even-weights superposition state of the form 
$$|\chi_\phi\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\frac{e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle,$$
and you need to specify a relative phase $\phi$ between the two (the global phase, on the other hand, is irrelevant), and if you don't have any more information then you can't know what to put in for $\phi$. One way to do this is to do an averaging where all the different phases are equally likely, and this gives you...
\begin{align}
\rho
& = \int_0^{2\pi} |\chi_\phi\rangle \langle \chi_\phi| \:\mathrm d\phi
\\& = \int_0^{2\pi}\frac12 \begin{pmatrix}1& e^{-i\phi} \\ e^{i\phi} & 1\end{pmatrix} \mathrm d\phi
\\& = \frac12 \begin{pmatrix}1& 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
the completely mixed state.

On the other hand, if you *do* have more information about the state (like measurement statistics on $S_x$ and $S_y$) then you can say more about the phase, but in such a generalized situation, there's very little more you can say.

---

And finally, as to how you prepare the positive-phase superposition,
$$|+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right\rangle,$$
the most convenient way is to measure $S_x$ and wait for an outcome of $+1/2$, but really, there's an infinite number of ways to arrive at that outcome, so it's not a particularly answerable question.

Answer (score 1):

Set up a Stern-Gerlach experiment, filter the beam about $\hat z$ with a magnetic gradient along this axis, measure the $\hat x$ component of spin:   your state is a combination of the $\pm$ eigenstates of $\sigma_x$.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you measure $S_z$ with equal probabilities of finding $=1/2$ or $-1/2$ it means that the spin system was prepared in a direction perpendicular to $z$. Without loss of generality let us call it the $x$ direction. The state you wrote is just the general state of spin in the $x$ direction, which is a linear combination
   $$|\chi\rangle=a|+1/2\rangle+b|-1/2\rangle,$$
   constrained to a normalization condition,
   $$|\langle\chi|\chi\rangle|^2=1,$$
   and to the probabilities of finding $S_z=\pm 1/2$ conditions,
   $$|\langle+1/2|\chi\rangle|^2=1/2, \quad |\langle-1/2|\chi\rangle|^2=1/2.$$
   The solution for the coeficientes is $a=e^{i\phi_1}/\sqrt 2$ and $b=e^{i\phi_2}/\sqrt 2$.
2. The state
   $$|+x\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\left(|+1/2\rangle+|-1/2\rangle\right),$$
   is such that when measuring $S_x$ it gives $+1/2$ always. Now let us say you start with an ensamble of spins prepared with $S_z=+1/2$. If you want now to prepare the system to the state $S_x=+1/2$, just rotate the apparatus (a Stern-Gerlach device for instance) into the $x$ direction and measure the spin. Half of the measurements will show $S_x=+1/2$ and those spins are all prepared into $|+x\rangle$. The other half gives $S_x=-1/2$ and are prepared into $|-x\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the spin state is not uniquely specified. You can actually omit the phase $e^{i\phi_1}$ and then $|{\chi}> = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}> + \frac{e^{i\phi}}{\sqrt2}|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}>$, since it doesn't matter if the system is isolated.
2. It's just like, when you know the direction of $\hat z$, can you point out the direction of $\hat x$ ?  No, you can only determine x-y plane and have to define $\hat x$ if you want. So you have to define the direction of $|\chi+> = \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}> + \frac{1}{\sqrt2}|\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}>$ first.

   Let's say the direction of $|\frac{1}{2},+\frac{1}{2}>$:  $\hat z$ , and the direction of your wanted $|\chi+>$:  $\hat x$ . You can then measure an ensemble of state in direction $\hat x$, and pick up those states that collapse into $|\chi+>$